# How to set Style on only Selected button from Group of Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two buttons Which is menioned in image
[image]

I have set the styles on it like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LinkButton" TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Style.Triggers>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
             Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="100">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"  From="0.2" To="0.2" ></DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Height="50" Width="52" Content="123" Style="{DynamicResource LinkButton}" Margin="64,42,401,227"/>
    <Button Height="50" Width="52" Content="456" Style="{DynamicResource LinkButton}" Margin="137,42,328,227"/>


</Grid>
```

the prob is when I click on first button 123 button the Opacity is set 0.2 which is good but I want when I click on 456 then 123 become normal and Opacity of 456 become a 0.2 how can I achive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the opacity to change only when the button has the focus. In this case you do not want to use an **EventTrigger** based on the Click event. Instead you want to use something like...

```
   <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                TargetName="border" 
                Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a btn click handler which would set some variable to this button clicked and when you click another button you reset the opacity to 1 of the previous pressed button.